# Logrotate for node.js app deployed using monit and upstart

Tags: node.js, monit, upstart, logrotate

I deployed a web application in node.js by following the guide: [Deploying Node.js With Upstart and Monit](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit) .

The app produces some log via `console.log()`. In the upstart script, it's redirected to a log file (`exec sudo -u www-data node app.js >> /var/log/app.log`).

How do I rotate this log? Do I need some particular treatment in the Javascript code? Can I send `kill -USR1` to nodejs like nginx?

Comment: Have you already tried actually doing it? what happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using upstart to manage your daemon, issue a reload in the logrotate config for your application. This should redirect your logging to the new file without disrupting the app.

Comment: Thanks, but `reload myapp` will actually shut down the app without restarting. My .conf (init) script do not have a reload section.